# Как правильно группировать страницы/статьи (Drupal 8)?

Tags: drupal, drupal8

При создание страницы/статьи, отсутствует возможность задать родителя данной страницы, можно лишь указать ее url. Как правильно указать родителя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно задать автора тогда заполните AUTHORING INFORMATION.
А если нужно построить иерархию в самом контенте, то есть

```
Node
- child
- child
- - child
- child
Node
- child
```

В Drupal 8 вы можете сделать это из коробки. Добавьте поле типа Reference content. Но если ссылаться на тот же тип содержимого и вы оставите поле Reference в режиме просмотра child существует риск бесконечного цикла, что приведет к тайм-аут

Если же нужно просто групировать материалы, тогда можно использовать таксономию. Создать словарь таксономии Types news с терминами

```
Главные новости
Спорт
  футбол
  Хокей
```

Потом создать поле формата Taxonomy term и выбрать там созданный словарь таксономии. Дальше при создании новости просто выбираеться категория, а кто кому родитель определяеться в самой таксономии

Comment: Я немного другое имел ввиду. Я хочу понять, как в Drupal вообще задаются родители, ну т.е. как группировать например новости. Нужно создать таксономию `новости` и к этой таксономии цеплять страницы с новостями?

Comment: да, лучше правда создать перед этим отдельный контент тип для новостей. В общем да, вся организация контента в большей степени делаеться через таксономию